# TM4J Java does not generate json result

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber, junit4, cucumber-java

I'm trying to make the integration between JUnit, Jenkins and TM4J (Jira) using this tutorial: https://support.smartbear.com/tm4j-cloud/docs/api-and-test-automation/junit-integration.html.

The problem is that the tm4j_result.json file is NOT generated, although the result from the Cucumber integration is being generated successfully.

Is it possible to generate BOTH Cucumber and JUnit reports?

This is the Jenkins reference, which contains the exact same file pattern example and the bitbucket code in the reference shows **only**
[adaptivist library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBdeN.png) and [surefire listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDAj5.png)

Comment: I have the same problem after migration from Java 1.8 to 11

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question : "Is it possible to generate BOTH Cucumber and JUnit reports?"

I would answer there is no asking this, since from your automated tests project, you will "either" work with BDD, hence use the cucumber file, or, work with non-BDD; which will in this case resort to the Junit file.
Should you have both, a solution using both will be needed at a pipeline level and a double test execution command will be deemed necessary to keep things reasonably simple.

There is no mix of BDD and non BDD all in the same test execution command, to put it simply !